# jQuery loop through data() object

Tags: jquery, loops, each

Is it possible to loop through a `data()` object?

Suppose this is my code:

```
$('#mydiv').data('bar','lorem');  
$('#mydiv').data('foo','ipsum');  
$('#mydiv').data('cam','dolores');
```

How do I loop through this? Can `each()` be used for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

jQuery stores all the data information in the jQuery.cache internal variable. It is possible to get all the data associated with a particular object with this simple but helpful plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.allData = function() {
    var intID = jQuery.data(this.get(0));
    return(jQuery.cache[intID]);
};
```

With this in place, you can do this:

```
$('#myelement').data('test1','yay1')
               .data('test2','yay2')
               .data('test3','yay3');

$.each($('#myelement').allData(), function(key, value) {
    alert(key + "=" + value);
});
```

You could just use matt b's suggestion but this is how to do it with what you have right now.

Comment: If it's an internal variable, isn't that subject to change in later versions of jquery (probably without notice)?

Comment: I'm sure they could, but I'm not sure why they would. Any retooling they might do to the data functionality would likely include this functionality built-in anyways. I don't think it's really a valid reason to shy away from it, but I guess it's a concern to keep in mind.

Answer (score 22):

```
$.each($.data(this), function(i, e) {
   alert('name='+ i + ' value=' +e);
});
```

This will iterate through each property in 'this' element's data object.

Comment: This didn't work OOTB for me, I had to slightly modify it: `$.each($('#mydiv').data(), function (i, e) { alert(i + ":" + e); });`

Answer (score 10):

Tested with jQuery 1.4 and tips from @user292614 the following works:

```
$('#mydiv').data('bar','lorem');  
$('#mydiv').data('foo','ipsum');  
$('#mydiv').data('cam','dolores');

$.each( $('#mydiv').data(),function(i, e) {
   alert('name='+ i + ' value=' +e);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

I don't think that there is any function that gives you all of the "keys" of the data that has been added with the `data()` function, but instead, why not put all of your data into the function under an object / map?

something like this:

```
var container = new Object();
container.bar = "lorem";
container.foo = "ipsum";
container.cam = "dolores";
$("mydiv").data("container", container);
```

and then when you want to read the data / iterate through it:

```
var blah = $("mydiv").data("container");
for(key in blah) {
    var value = blah[key];
    //do whatever you want with the data, such as:
    console.log("The value of ", key, " is ", value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this but needed some extra data values. If you also got this "problem" then the following should work.

```
$('#mydiv').data('bar', {name:'lorem', id:'156', price:'199'});
```

then you can simply extend with the value id

```
$.each( $('#mydiv').data(),function(i, e) {
   alert('name='+ i + ' name=' +e.name + ' id='e.id + ' price=' + e.price );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If we use .data() means it store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.

and if .data() in loop so we have to access it same manner in loop so for e.g(below)

```
<p class="weekday" data-today="monday">Monday</p>
<p class="weekday" data-today="tuesday">Tuesday</p>
<p class="weekday" data-today="wednesday">Wednesday</p>
<p class="weekday" data-today="thursday">Thursday</p>
```

The html in my loop and `data-today` is same in all tags but their values are different so basically it is loop generated `html` so we have to access in same manner i.e loop in `js/jQuery` for e.g. `(below jQuery code)`

`$('.weekday').each(function(){
   $(this).data('today');
 });`

`OutPut :`

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
```

NOTE : In browser console it return particular `<DIV>`.