# Get all attributes of element is working different on IE

Tags: jquery

If you run this script http://jsfiddle.net/y8jp8/2/ on IE7 and firefox you can see: 
Results are not the same.

I just want to see just 3 attribute (id, title and myattr) and it's values. How can I do this in IE?

Comment: **each ID** element ... shouldn't ID be one and one only?

Comment: @roXon Huh? Each ID element? Where does the OP say that?

Comment: I misunderstand the Q. Exploring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you can't just get the three explicit values you want instead of iterating over all attributes? This gets me the same results in IE7 and Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/y8jp8/22/

```
var result = "";
result += 'id=' + $('#sample').attr('id') + '<br />';
result += 'title=' + $('#sample').attr('title') + '<br />';
result += 'myattr=' + $('#sample').attr('myattr') + '<br />';
$("#log").html( result );
```

Comment: On my application I stored to many value on elements attribute. Those attribute count may varry. I know, if I change those attribute names with prefix data- (on html5) I can easly get with jQuery data methode <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999535/how-to-get-from-an-element-all-the-data-set-using-the-data-method>

Comment: Until change my code to jQuery data methode, I can use this code. But, this is not a perfect solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is a correction to roXon's answer, but still no perfect solution..

```
var result = "";
var attrs = $("#sample")[0].attributes;

for(var i=0;i<attrs.length;i++) {
    if(attrs[i].nodeValue != null 
    && attrs[i].nodeValue != '' 
    && attrs[i].nodeValue != 'inherit'){
        result += ( attrs[i].nodeName + "=" + attrs[i].nodeValue + "<br>");
    }

    $('#log').html(result);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/digitaloutback/pMVJw/9/

**UPDATE:**

IE7 doesn't seem to filter out the unspecified attributes, for example, this is the data for the 'sample' attribute in your example:

```
parentNode => null 
nodeValue => sample 
firstChild => null 
name => id 
expando => false 
lastChild => null 
ownerDocument => [object] 
attributes => null 
previousSibling => null 
value => sample 
nodeType => 2 
nodeName => id 
childNodes => null 
nextSibling => null 
specified => true 
ownerElement => undefined
```

Therefore, you need to test against 'specified' like:

```
var result = "";
var attrs = $("#sample")[0].attributes;

for(var i=0;i<attrs.length;i++) {   

    if(attrs[i].specified === true ) {
        result += ( attrs[i].nodeName + "=" + attrs[i].nodeValue + "<br>");
    }

    $('#log').html(result);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/digitaloutback/pMVJw/10/

Comment: This solution is NOT work if I empty my attibute: `<div id="sample" title="" myattr=""></div>` I still want to list 3 attribute.