# jquery data() - how to read out all key/value pairs?

Tags: jquery, object

I'm trying to understand a jquery script which stores an object using jquery data().

Is there an easy way to retrieve all information stored? Especially since I don't know all of the keys that have been used.

Thanks for help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772608/jquery-loop-through-data-object - this answer might help you

Comment: @Alex I'm pretty sure that answer is outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call [`.data()` with no arguments](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2), it returns what you want.

```
var allData = $('some-element-selector').data();
for (var k in allData)
{
    if (allData.hasOwnProperty(k))
    {
        console.log(k + ':' + allData[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: just calling data() returns [object Object]. Trying your function.

Comment: That's why you have to iterate through it to get the values

Comment: @frequent correction: calling `.data().toString()` returns `'[object Object]`. Start using a real debugger instead of `alert()`.

Comment: @Matt: I used to alert()... console.log is more convenient although I have not quite figured my way around Firebug... Thx!