# How exactly does .data() attach data to elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does jQuery .data() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764619/how-does-jquery-data-work)

```
 <script>
    $("div").data("test", { first: 16, last: "pizza!" });
    </script>
```

I thought, via Google Chrome Developer Tools, i could see something like:

```
<div first="16" last="pizza!"></div>
```

but i couldn't.

How exactly does .data() attach data to elements?
Is there a chance i can see/inspect data without invoking .data() method?

Comment: Have a look at the non-minimized code http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js and search for `data:`. It's quite good commented. Also if jquery would actually place those attributes on the node. It would use `data-first` and `data-last`. Which allready works to prefill data values like `data-placeholder="foo"` would init `.data('placeholder')` as `foo`.

Comment: You are looking for this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772608/jquery-loop-through-data-object

Comment: Why would you want to do that.. You are breaking the abstraction then

Answer (score 0):

From this question: [How does jQuery .data() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764619/how-does-jquery-data-work)
it seems jQuery holds an internal cache-object to store the items. From that answer you'll also see it's possible to do this via the javascript-console through:

```
 $.cache
```

which will give you all of the values, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You should not answer a question by just repeating another answer. If a question can be answered this way, it is a duplicate and should be closed as such.