# Inspect data stored on elements using data() method

Tags: jquery, firebug

Is there any plugin for firebug that lets you inspect data stored on elements using the `data()` method?

Thanks

Comment: The Data stored on elements can be inspected if you navigate to the elements in Firebug

Comment: @joberror Ok, where do I find it?

Comment: @joberror that's not true, in Firebug you just see the html5 data attribute which are used as defaults (if set).

Comment: @DavidThomas I dont want to use the get part of the data method since i want to debug using firebug directly instead of printing stuff to its console.

Comment: In which case I'd point you to this question: [jQuery loop through `data()` object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772608/jquery-loop-through-data-object).

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: I guess that's true cos currently my code is based on HTML5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself: http://firequery.binaryage.com/

Answer (score 0):

`.data()` stores the data in an internal cache so there is no easy way to know what is attached to each element. The html5 data attributes, if set, are used for initial values of `.data()`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel like installing a plugin, you can use the regular Firebug debugger. Simply copy the data object into a local variable first.

```
var myDataAll = $("#myElement").data();
// Stop at the next line in the debugger and examine myDataAll.
```

or

```
var myDataSpecific = $("#myElement").data("myKey");
// Stop at the next line in the debugger and examine myDataSpecific.
```